# При клике ошибка Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".square")

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].onclick = function(){
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    }
}
```

```css
.square{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
        <div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а так?

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".square")

for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].onclick = function(){
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    }
}
```

```css
.square{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
```

против

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".square")

for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].onclick = function(){
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    }
}
```

```css
.square{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
```

и ещё пример

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".square")

for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].onclick = function(){
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    }
}

console.log(window.i)
```

```css
.square{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
```

против

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".square")

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].onclick = function(){
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    }
}

console.log(window.i)
```

```css
.square{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
        <div class = "square"></div>
```

Comment: А почему без let не работает, всмысле мы же задаем без let-а переменную а так без let не работает

Comment: потому что без let это глобальная переменная

Comment: а без let какая?, var? он же тоже такой

Comment: без let это var, а точнее window.i